# How to generate yup schema from typescript interface

Tags: typescript, yup

I have a number of interfaces declared in `typescript`. I want to covert them into `yup` schemas, is there 'ready to use' solutions to do this programmatically and not manually?

Comment: https://github.com/Code-Hex/graphql-codegen-typescript-validation-schema

Comment: Yup tried to do it on itselft : https://github.com/jquense/yup#ensuring-a-schema-matches-an-existing-type. But the solution still has issues.